# Add SiteName CustomFilter - RefinementPanel

Tags: search-results, refinement-panel

Here is an excerpt of my current code:

  `<Category Title="Departments" Description="Use this filter to restrict results authored by a specific site" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"  MetadataThreshold="0"  NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="20"  MaxNumberOfFilters="20"  SortBy="Frequency"  SortByForMoreFilters="Name"  SortDirection="Descending"  SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"  ShowMoreLink="false" MappedProperty="SiteName"  MoreLinkText="show more"  LessLinkText="show fewer">
    <CustomFilters MappingType="ValueMapping" DataType="String" ValueReference="Absolute" ShowAllInMore="False">
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Intranet Home">
        <OriginalValue>replaced.domain.com</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Human Resources">
        <OriginalValue>replaced.domain.com&#47;hr</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Information Systems">
        <OriginalValue>replaced.domain.com&#47;is</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
    </CustomFilters>
  </Category>`

`

Of Course this isn't throwing an exception; however, neither is it functional.  It should be but, alas I cannot event get the 'department' refinement to show on the page.  There obviously, is something I am doing incorrectly.  I am also, sure that I don't need to extend the managed metadata to support and OOTB filter.  I could be wrong here as well.

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it without escaping the slashes? (e.g. replaced.domain.com/is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the raw answer:

All Refinements are based upon current domain and filtering by values will work from current location down regardless of having the ValueReference Attribute set.  You evidently can only use Relative Values for locations and not full direct values.

The only choice is to extend the refinement panel and create Absolute Path Refinements (if you do this make sure to build a solution for removed paths/sites).